# Challenging a patent application

Tags: process

A PCT has been published, in its National Phase, in the US on 18 Oct 2018. I have formally challenged this through the proper channels and assume that it will fail to be granted (it is entirely based on a previous GB patent which has already been withdrawn).

My question is how long do you think it might take for the examiner to rule on it and quosh it completely ?